# Allow a user to upload a PDF file to a specific block within a page

Tags: views, nodes

Wondering if anyone can help with a problem:

I have created a content type called 'Brochures' and added a 'file' field with a pdf format. I want the user to be able to upload pdf file(s) then select a particular page for the pdf to populate having them display in a block-view on that specific page.
So the user process would be:

-add content
-select 'Brochure' content type 
-browse/upload PDF 
-select a page for the PDF to populate <-----This is the part that is giving me grey hair. ;)
 
-save

Hope I am making sense.

Always, Jason﻿

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module to add the "Select a page for the PDF to populate" field (in the "Brochure" content type).

Then, create a View block that filters on "content type = brochure" and which pulls the PDF file field only. Set up a Contextual Filter for the entity reference field (the one that you selected the node/page for the PDF to populate on) and provide a default value of the nid of the page being viewed.

Placing this block in a region should pull related PDFs for pages that have been referenced. Should work!

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!!!  It worked!  :)  

I was using the 'relationship' filter not the contextual filter.  (I am very new to Drupal obviously).   lol